# Shemonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

180 were the years of Yitzchak's life
- Bereishit 35:28

180 is the number of days Achashveirosh's feast lasted.
- Megillat Esther, 1:4

180 prophets rose up amongst the Jews
- Megillah 14 (according to Ramban's version Dvarim 4:2)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13047.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rashi and other Mifarshim both Avraham Avinu and Yaakov Avinu were supposed to live 180 years, just like Yitzchok Avinu. However, Hashem shortened the life of Avraham in order for him not to see Eisav doing Aveiros. Yaakov's life was shortened due to the conversation he had with Pahro.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13047.

Answer (score 1):

In the Jewish year 3622, during the time of the second Bais HaMikdash, the Kingdom of Rome took control, together with the Chashmona'im. This occurred **180 years** after Yavan dominated the Jews.

Answer (score 0):

The International Date Line is a north-south imaginary line on the surface of the Earth, passing through the middle of the Pacific Ocean, where the date changes as a ship or airplane travels east or west across it. It is roughly along **180°** longitude. This has significant value as to whether it is Shabbos or not, fasting a extra day for Yom Kippur and many more Halachic questions.

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues